# momentjs converting single numeric month to double

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I m trying to convert single numeric month into double-digit e.g 00 that I got from user to numbers with the following code

```
currentMonthNumeric: moment().format('M'),
```

How can I get months to convert from a single (0) to double (00)

Comment: Actually *Base 0* would return `6` for July where January would be `0`. So likely something else is the problem. Possibly a difference in timezone than what you are expecting for that particular set of inputs, but not all inputs.

Comment: Well.. it depends what currentMonthNumeric is but you could just + 1...

Comment: simply you can add 1 with the result

Comment: @DanielTate `.add(1, 'month)` or how?

Comment: @Nofel this.currentMonthNumeric + 1

Comment: @GetSet ur right, the problem is something else as July is 08 and so is August 08.  If I use `this.currentMonthNumeric` which gives me the right single digit. how can I make it double digit?

Comment: @Nofel, the problem is/was `currentMonthNumeric` is in Base 1 because that's what `.format("M")` and `format("MM")` returns. It then goes on to get formatted again when `.month()` expects Base 0

Comment: So you could solve this by subtracting 1 from your `currentMonthNumeric` to restore it to Base 0, which your later `.month()` API calls will expect it to be in. ... And when you call that format on a Base 0 number, it will add 1 for display purposes. The `MM` option gives  you the leading 0.

Comment: @GetSet @Nofel I think you are complicating the issue this is a simple syntactical misunderstanding. `moment(yourDate, 'yourDateFormat').format('formatYouWant')`

You pass in your date and then the date format it is in (so `moment('7', 'M')`) then format it to whatever you want (so `.format('MM')`).

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a small syntax error.

```js
const currentMonthNumeric = moment().format('M')
console.log("currentMonthNumeric: " + currentMonthNumeric);
// Your code which is using moment a bit wrong I believe
console.log("Wrong code: " + moment().month(currentMonthNumeric).format('MM')); // current month + 1 in double format e.g. 08
// Correct implementation I believe
console.log("Correct code: " + moment(currentMonthNumeric, 'MM').format('MM')); // current month in double format e.g. 07

// Single month to double example
const singleMonthStatic = "7";
// Wrong code
console.log("Wrong code static: " + moment().month(singleMonthStatic).format('MM')); // 08
// Correct code
console.log("Correct code static: " + moment(singleMonthStatic, 'M').format('MM')); // 07

// Also if you just want double from the start

const currentMonthDoubleNumeric = moment().format('MM')
console.log("currentMonthDoubleNumeric: " + currentMonthDoubleNumeric); // current month in double e.g. 07
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You didn't *reproduce* the OP's problem because you have no idea what OP's `this` value is.

Comment: They said: where currentMonthNumeric: moment().format('M')

Comment: True otw, but in OP's timezone or yours? Generally the month wouldn't change, unless on the cusps. Further, OP doesn't show the code with this claim in source form. Unless the OP meant `06` for July and not `08`.

Comment: @GetSet I added OP's code to show you how their implementation is wrong. But you are right I should edit this to be timezone agnostic.

Comment: Upvoted because in reading the docs, the `.format("M")` and `.format("MM")` are going to return the month in *Base 1*. But the `.month()` method accepts it's parameter in *Base 0*. Therefore the format in this case returns `7`. But when passed to the Base 0 call, and "reformatted" by a subsequent call to the other, `7` becomes `8`.

Comment: @Nofel my response still answers your question. Your syntax is wrong.

Comment: @Nofel I am editing the example to show you for single month.

Comment: @GetSet using `.month()` is not needed here at all.